# Preventing spaCy splitting paragraph numbers into sentences

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, sentence

I'm using spaCy to do sentence segmentation on texts that using paragraph numbering, for example:

```
text = '3. English law takes a dim view of stealing stuff from the shops. Some may argue that this is a pity.'
```

I'm trying to force spaCy's sentence segmenter to not split the `3.` into a sentence of it's own.

At the moment, the following code returns three separate sentences:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

text = """3. English law takes a dim view of stealing stuff from the shops. Some may argue that this is a pity."""
doc = nlp(text)
for sent in doc.sents:
    print("****", sent.text)
```

This returns:

```
**** 3.
**** English law takes a dim view of stealing stuff from the shops.
**** Some may argue that this is a pity.
```

I've been trying to stop this from happening by passing a custom rule into the pipeline before the parser:

```
if token.text == r'\d\.':
    doc[token.i+1].is_sent_start = False
```

This is doesn't seem to have any effect. Has anyone come across this problem before?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: While this does not answer the question, as this is about SpaCy, I may suggest  my own sentence segmentation and tokenization tool, [segtok](https://github.com/fnl/segtok), and its latest incarnation, "segtok version 2", [syntok](https://github.com/fnl/syntok). Neither splits sentences at enumerations, and syntok even fixes cases like "This is a sentence.And here we forgot a space.", while the token stream retains the original input, and being a very performant, production-ready, high-quality sentence segmenter for at least English, Spanish, and German. You might want to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
text = ["""3. English law takes a dim view of stealing stuff from the shops. Some may argue that this is a pity. Are you upto something?""", 
        """4. It's hilarious and I think this can be more of a political moment. Don't you think so? Will Robots replace humans?"""]
for i in text:
    doc = nlp(i)
    span = doc[0:5]
    span.merge()
    for sent in doc.sents:
        print("****", sent.text)
    print("\n")
```

Output:

```
**** 3. English law takes a dim view of stealing stuff from the shops.
**** Some may argue that this is a pity.
**** Are you upto something?


**** 4. It's hilarious and I think this can be more of a political moment.
**** Don't you think so?
**** Will Robots replace humans?
```

Reference: [span.merge()](https://spacy.io/api/span#merge)